# Question about annihilators of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is that true, for a finitely generated module $M$ over a p.i.d. $R$, that $$\operatorname{Ann}_{M}(sr)=\operatorname{Ann}_M(s) \oplus \operatorname{Ann}_M(r),$$ when $r,s\in R$ are prime elements?

Comment: What do you denote $\operatorname{Ann}_r(M)$ and the like?

Comment: I define $\mathrm{Ann}_r(M):=\{M\in M s.t. rm=0$, with $r\in R$ a regular element

Comment: I suppose you mean $\;\{\color{red}m \in M\mid rm=0\}$?

Comment: Yes sorry I was about to edit it

Comment: This submodule is usually denoted  $\;\operatorname{Ann}_M(r)\;$ or $\;0:_M (r)$.

Comment: Thank you I made an edit

Comment: Obviously you need $r$ and $s$ to be distinct for the sum to be a direct sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me use the notation $\ker x = \{m ∈ M; xm = 0\}$ for $x ∈ R$.

Yes, that’s true, and you only need $r, s ∈ R$ to be comaximal and commuting elements. This is certainly the case for distinct primes in a principal ideal domain.

So obviously, we have

- $\ker r ⊆ \ker sr$ and $\ker s ⊆ \ker rs$, so
- $\ker r + \ker s ⊆ \ker rs$, as $r$ and $s$ commute.

Now, since $r$ and $s$ are comaximal, there are some $a, b ∈ R$ with $1 = ar + bs$. Hence:

- For any $m ∈ \ker r ∩ \ker s$, we have $m = 1·m = …$
- For any $m ∈ \ker rs$, we have $sm ∈ \ker r$ and, as $rs = sr$, $rm ∈ \ker s$. So $m = 1·m = …$.